# Oracle - Query inside query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create users in oracle, using my existing table call EMPLOYEE, I want to generate a query to create users with user name. User name is in EMPLOYEE table.

I want to create a query like below

```
CREATE USER (SELECT first_name FROM employee where employee_id = '1') 
IDENTIFIED BY password .....so on
```

Comment: Mind expanding this with more details?  Do you have a User table your are trying to populate from the Employee table?  What SQL have you tried?

Comment: Yes. EMPLOYEE table. it includes first_name

Comment: I have tried the above code

Answer (score 4):

DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT can be used to run DDL statements in PLSQL so you can try the below

```
BEGIN
FOR c IN (select 'CREATE USER  ' || first_name || ' ' || 'IDENTIFIED BY ' ||
                 password_column ||' ' as rec
            from employee where employee_id=1) LOOP
  begin
    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement(c.rec);
  exception
    when others then
      dbms_output.enable;
dbms_output.put_line  ('failed for '||c.rec);
dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    end;
  END LOOP;
  END;
```

Comment: this will create user based on first_name from Employee Table

Comment: @ArunaDissanayake, hi. Your problem is that you can't use subqueries in CREATE USER statements. The alternative is the one proposed by psaraj12 that consists in dynamically creating and executing as many CREATE USER statement as you have users in your table. However for the sake of safety I would rather export them to the console than execute them on the fly, at least until you know the code works as you intend.

Comment: Good answer, but i recommend you do not use when other then null, because you are hiding possible errors that can occurs